# Why does my program display the Array address instead of its contents?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

My C program consists of an array called 'test_var'. It has another integer array 'arr_int' that consists of a set of integer numbers. My code looks something like this:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stddef.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 int State(var);
 int main()
       {
         int arr_int[3] ={1000, 1001, 1002, 1003};
         int var;
         int *test_var[4]={0};

         State(var)
         {
            int i;
            for(i=0; i<4; i++){
               test_var[i] = arr_int[i];
               i++;
                }
          return test_var[var];
          }

          printf("Enter a number between 0 and 3\n");
          scanf("%d",&var);   
          State(var);
          printf ("The array structure is %d", test_var[var]);

          return 0;
          }
```

However now when I try to print the returned value array test_var for the user input var=0 instead of the whole array(1000) I just get 0. What am I doing wrong here ? COuld somebody please tell me? Am I dereferencing the array in a wrong way?

EDIT : the code without the typo:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stddef.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 int State(var);
 int main()
       {
         int *arr_int[3] ={1000, 1001, 1002, 1003};
         int var;
         int *test_var[4]={0};

         State(var)
         {
            int i;
            for(i=0; i<4; i++){
               test_var[i] = arr_int[i];
               i++;
                }
          return test_var[var];
          }

          printf("Enter a number between 0 and 3\n");
          scanf("%d",&var);   
          State(var);
          printf ("The array structure is %d", test_var[var]);

          return 0;
          }
```

Comment: What is that: int `State(var);`? Not C, definitely. Unless `State` is macro. Update ah, a nested function. Not a standard C. And without parameter type... Please don't do that.

Comment: in `int arr_int[3] = {1000, 1001, 1002, 1003};`, `[3]` indicates that you want array of 3 integers but you defined 4.

Comment: Before going any further, I recommend turning warnings up to a higher level, and fixing the syntax errors you have.  e.g. `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra`, or the equivalent if you use a different compiler.  You seem to be using a bunch of extensions that are not C, and it's hard to diagnose non-standard code.

Comment: What is this `int State(var);` and this `State(var) {...`.? I doubt this will ever compile.

Answer (score 1):

In your case,

1. the statement

   ```
   test_var[i] = arr_int[i];
   ```

   is wrong. `test_var[i]` is of type `int *`, and `arr_int[i]` is of type `int`, and they are not really compatible. To quote the standard, chapter §6.3.2.3

   > An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.
2. Then, you're using another statement like

   ```
   printf ("The array structure is %d", test_var[var]);
   ```

   `%d` expects an `int` argument, but you're supplying an `int *`. Pure  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
3. After that, `int State(var)` relies upon the older concept of *default-to-`int`*, which has been made invalid in `C99` onwards.
4. In an array of 3 elements, you're supplying 4-member initializer list. Useless and confusing.

That said, FWIW, you're using a *nested function*, which is also not a part of standard C. [It is supported as a GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html).

---

**EDIT:**

As per the comments, even if your `arr_int` is an array of of type `int *`, the initializers do not provide a seemingly *valid* value for the pointers to be dereferenced. That means, you cannot access the memory pointed to by those pointers, they are most likely to reside outside of the allocated memory area of your process and hence, invalid.

Nevertheless, for the point 2, mentioned earlier, the code is UB.

Comment: Silly me! I skipped the * while posting the question here. They are of the same type (int *) actually. Sorry for the confusion..

Comment: @Goldengirl Can you edit your post to **add (append)** the actual code without the typo?

Comment: @Goldengirl is not it like yesterday itself I asked you not to **edit out** the original code? I mean, which part of **append** was not clear?

Comment: I had made an edit to the code initially(without changing it) but looking at your add(and missing the append) I edited it...sry for it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr_int[3] ={1000, 1001, 1002, 1003};
```

Array is of size `3` you initialize it with `4` elements.

Also the nested function is supposed to create a problem.They are supported as an extension in GNU C.

**Note**-Though you can declare a function inside of a function, but it's not a nested function.

---

### EDIT

Your second code when you give input as `0` and `2` it seems to give correct output but when input is `1` or `3` it gives as `0`. Surely it doesn't behave as intended.

Comment: @ameyCU : Would that create a problem? Wouldn't C just skip the last value 1003 if there is no space in the array?

Comment: Warning will be issued .

Comment: `Though you can declare a function inside of a function, but it's not a nested function.`...so what/how is it?

Comment: @SouravGhosh  Defining  and declaration are two different things . And declaration wont be called as nested.

Comment: @ameyCU I think I know that. I'm bothered about the usage of the _declaration_. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh  Well ofcourse you know Sir !! but I don't follow about declaration can you please make it clear for me.

Comment: @ameyCU how the declaration will be helpful in that case?

Comment: @SouravGhosh  Ohh now I get it .It was supposed to be a note just for knowledge , not insisting to use it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *arr_int[3] ={1000, 1001, 1002, 1003};
int *test_var[4]={0};
```

Why did you declare pointers instead of arrays? And why arr_int[3] is initialized with 4 integers?

It should be like this.

```
int arr_int[3] ={1000, 1001, 1002};
int test_var[4]={0}
```